# Authenticating embedded Kibana iframe with AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a web app which already uses AWS Cognito to authenticate my users. These users have been granted role-based access to the Kibana URL of my AWS ElasticSearch cluster. But when I provided an embedded kibana dashboard iframe into my user's session, it doesn't work. I think I need to pass the Cognito session information along with the iframe. Is there a way to pass the Cognito session information along with the iframe? The embedded dashboard starts working when I login to Kibana in a separate browser tab, which leads me to believe this is an authentication issue. Any pointers will be of great help! Thanks.